# How to use fetch in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise, fetch-api

I am using [window.fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in Typescript, but I cannot cast the response directly to my custom type:

I am hacking my way around this by casting the Promise result to an intermediate 'any' variable.

What would be the correct method to do this?

```
import { Actor } from './models/actor';

fetch(`http://swapi.co/api/people/1/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
          // this is not allowed
          // let a:Actor = <Actor>res;

          // I use an intermediate variable a to get around this...
          let a:any = res; 
          let b:Actor = <Actor>a;
      })
```

Comment: Uh, `json` contains plain objects, so how could you cast it to an instance? You'd need to use something like `Actor.from` that creates a `new Actor` with the data.

Comment: Why is it "not allowed"? What error do you get when you try it?

Comment: and which definitions are you using because [fetch isn't in typescript libs yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12493)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I just discovered the error: I have to say that res is of type any. .then((res:any) => { let b = <Actor>res}). Then it's actually allowed. @MeirionHughes I am using the definitelyTyped whatwg-fetch.d.ts files to make typescript recognise fetch.

Comment: @Bergi [fetch is now implemented in ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13856)

Comment: @Timo Was this comment supposed to be directed at Meirion?

Comment: @MeirionHughes fetch is now implemented in ts.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

## Edit

There has been some changes since writing this answer a while ago. As mentioned in the comments, `response.json<T>` is no longer valid. Not sure, couldn't find where it was removed.

For later releases, you can do:

```
// Standard variation
function api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
      }
      return response.json() as Promise<T>
    })
}


// For the "unwrapping" variation

function api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
      }
      return response.json() as Promise<{ data: T }>
    })
    .then(data => {
        return data.data
    })
}
```

## Old Answer

A few examples follow, going from basic through to adding transformations after the request and/or error handling:

## Basic:

```
// Implementation code where T is the returned data shape
function api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
      }
      return response.json<T>()
    })

}

// Consumer
api<{ title: string; message: string }>('v1/posts/1')
  .then(({ title, message }) => {
    console.log(title, message)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    /* show error message */
  })
```

## Data transformations:

Often you may need to do some tweaks to the data before its passed to the consumer, for example, unwrapping a top level data attribute. This is straight forward:

```
function api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
      }
      return response.json<{ data: T }>()
    })
    .then(data => { /* <-- data inferred as { data: T }*/
      return data.data
    })
}

// Consumer - consumer remains the same
api<{ title: string; message: string }>('v1/posts/1')
  .then(({ title, message }) => {
    console.log(title, message)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    /* show error message */
  })
```

## Error handling:

I'd argue that you shouldn't be directly error catching directly within this service, instead, just allowing it to bubble, but if you need to, you can do the following:

```
function api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText)
      }
      return response.json<{ data: T }>()
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data.data
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      externalErrorLogging.error(error) /* <-- made up logging service */
      throw error /* <-- rethrow the error so consumer can still catch it */
    })
}

// Consumer - consumer remains the same
api<{ title: string; message: string }>('v1/posts/1')
  .then(({ title, message }) => {
    console.log(title, message)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    /* show error message */
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the best explanation of generics I've read so far. It's still a bit vague why a Promise can be of a type, while it's actually the data that has the type...

Comment: Great! I've been exploring this part of TS more recently, so its helpful for me to jot down my notes. Which part is confusing? - happy to expand on it

Comment: I'd expect that it's not the Promise that has the `<T>` type, but the content that is being fetched. But apparently you can tell that to the Promise class? (Is a Promise a class? a function? an object?)

Comment: What if I have the errors in the response body rather than in the status text (and I can't control that)

Comment: Just replace `if (!response.ok) {` with whatever check you need

Comment: The response.json method does not seem to be defined as generic -- neither in the current `@types/node-fetch`, nor in the current TypeScript `lib.dom.d.ts` -- so this answer isn't feasible now. So instead I guess we have to do `return response.json() as Promise<T>;`?

Comment: @ChrisW You're correct it has changed. I've updated the answer

Comment: For those interested you can add an optional parameter `unwrapParam?: string` to make the unwrap more generic: `return (response.json() as Promise<{ [wrapParam: string]: T }>).then((data) => data[unwrapParam]`

Comment: how can promise.json() be a Promise?

Comment: @RahulYadav https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json#return_value

Answer (score 14):

Actually, pretty much anywhere in typescript, passing a value to a function with a specified type will work as desired as long as the type being passed is compatible.

That being said, the following works...

```
 fetch(`http://swapi.co/api/people/1/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((res: Actor) => {
          // res is now an Actor
      });
```

I wanted to wrap all of my http calls in a reusable class - which means I needed some way for the client to process the response in its desired form.  To support this, I accept a callback lambda as a parameter to my wrapper method.  The lambda declaration accepts an any type as shown here...

```
callBack: (response: any) => void
```

But in use the caller can pass a lambda that specifies the desired return type.  I modified my code from above like this...

```
fetch(`http://swapi.co/api/people/1/`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
      if (callback) {
        callback(res);    // Client receives the response as desired type.  
      }
  });
```

So that a client can call it with a callback like...

```
(response: IApigeeResponse) => {
    // Process response as an IApigeeResponse
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at [@types/node-fetch](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node-fetch/index.d.ts) you will see the body definition

```js
export class Body {
    bodyUsed: boolean;
    body: NodeJS.ReadableStream;
    json(): Promise<any>;
    json<T>(): Promise<T>;
    text(): Promise<string>;
    buffer(): Promise<Buffer>;
}
```

That means that you could use generics in order to achieve what you want. I didn't test this code, but it would looks something like this:

```
import { Actor } from './models/actor';

fetch(`http://swapi.co/api/people/1/`)
      .then(res => res.json<Actor>())
      .then(res => {
          let b:Actor = res;
      });
```

Comment: Adding the generic type results in `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1`, but perhaps that's because I don't use `node-fetch`. The types for native fetch are probably different?

Comment: the linked file does not have a templated `json()`. if it existed before, it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Sorry to dredge up an old post, but, the `Body.json<T>` signature was removed from DefinitelyTyped in 2018 with [this commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/78cdbac#diff-16dd1699972b26236bcd5bc367af23fbL128).  Browsing through the history of [**node-fetch** > `/src/body.js`](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/master/src/body.js), I'm not sure I ever see a time where `json()` was implemented this way.  Nico, do you have an example of this working, otherwise, I'm inclined to think this doesn't.

Comment: Well I took that from some code I had in 2017... I don't know the state of this right now

Answer (score 2):

This is specifically written for `POST` request. That is why it has "variables" parameter. In case of "GET" request same code will work, vriables can be optional is handled

```
export type FetcherOptions = {
  queryString: string
  variables?: FetcherVariables
}

export type FetcherVariables = {[key: string]: string | any | undefined}

export type FetcherResults<T> = {
  data: T
}

const fetcher = async <T>({queryString, 
                           variables }: FetcherOptions): Promise<FetcherResults<T>> => {
  const res = await fetch(API_URL!, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // You can add more headers
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      queryString,
      variables
    })
  })
  const { data, errors} = await res.json()

  if (errors) {
    // if errors.message null or undefined returns the custom error
    throw new Error(errors.message ?? "Custom Error" )
  }

  return { data }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular use-case:

"Fetching data from a remote resource, we do not have control and want to validate filter before injecting in our current application"

I feel recommending zod npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod

with the following fashion:

```
// 1. Define a schema

const Data = z.object({
  // subset of real full type
  name: z.string(),
  // unExpectedAttr: z.number(), --> enabling this will throw ZodError 
  height: z.string(),
  mass: z.string(),
  films: z.array(z.string()),
});

// 2. Infer a type from the schema to annotate the final obj

type DataType = z.infer<typeof Data>;

(async () => {
  try {
    const r = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/?format=json`);
    const obj: DataType = Data.parse(await r.json());
    console.log(obj); // filtered with expected field in Data Schema
    /**
     Will log:
     {
       name: 'Luke Skywalker',
       height: '172',
       mass: '77',
       films: [
        'https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'
       ]
     }
    */

  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ZodError) {
      // Unexpected type in response not matching Data Schema
    } else {
      // general unexpected error
    }
  }
})();
```