# Typescript: how to structure a fetch API call inside a method that returns a Promise response

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, fetch

Maybe a trivial one, but I am new with Typescript and fetch API.
In an exported class I have a public method `remoteFetchSomething` like:

```
export class className {
  remoteFetchSomething = (url : string) : Promise<Response> => {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(
        (r) => r.json()
      )
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("API errore fetching " + objectType);
      });
  }
}

export const classInstance = new className();
```

The method queries a remote JSON API service, and in the code, I am using it like:

```
import { classInstance } from ...

classInstance.remoteFetchSomething('https://example.url')
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
  }
)
```

The `console.log` is actually showing the results, but the `remoteFetchSomething` returns a *Promise* and I am unable to parse and access the JSON object values.

I would like to wait for the response before executing the remaining code, but how do I unwrap content from promise? Should I again put another `.then`? What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now I resolved the problem defining the return type of the `remoteFetch` as `any`:

```
remoteFetchSomething = (url : string) : any => {
return fetch(url)
  .then(
    (r) => r.json()
  )
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("API errore fetching " + objectType);
  });
}
```

And now I can access JSON values like `data` below:

```
classInstance.remoteFetchSomething('https://example.url').then(
  (json) => {
    console.dump(json.data);
  }
)
```

[sincerely still not clear why I cant' use the `Promise<Response>` type]

Comment: Returning `any` defeats the purpose of static type checking. Using generics like in this example, seems a much better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471725/1275499

Answer (score 1):

You can't synchronously block while waiting for a request in javascript, it would lock up the user's interface!

In regular javascript, and most versions of TypeScript, you should be / must be returning a promise.

```
function doRequestNormal(): Promise<any> {
    return fetch(...).then(...);
}

function someOtherMethodNormal() {
    // do some code here
    doRequestNormal.then(() => {
        // continue your execution here after the request
    });
}
```

In newer versions of typescript, there's async/await keyword support - so instead it might look like this:

```
async function doRequestAsync() {
    var result = await fetch(...);
    // do something with request;
    return result;
}

async function someOtherMethodAsync() {
    // do some code here
    var json = await doRequestAsync();
    // continue some code here
}
```

Keep in mind, `doRequestAsync` still returns a Promise under the hood - but when you call it, you can use `await` to pretend that you're blocking on it instead of needing to use the `.then(` callback. If you call an async method from a non-async method, you'll still need to use the callbacks as normal.

Comment: Sorry, may be my question was not clear: the issue is not about the Promise chaining and waits, it was about the return type of the remoteFetchSomething method: being a `Response<Promise>` I was unable to parse the json on the other side. 
If i define the method return type to `any` it works.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it:

```
type Payload = {
    id: number
}

type ReturnType = number

export const functionThatHasNumberType = async (
    payload: Payload
): Promise<ReturnType> => {
    let url = `/api/${payload.id}`

    return await axios.get(url)
}
```