# TypeScript Fetch response.Json<T> - Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: typescript, fetch-api

forgive my ignorance but I am trying to implement a fetch in TypeScript and I have been going through the examples but cannot get it to compile.  I am new to TypeScript and Promise and I found this example:

[How to use fetch in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103360/how-to-use-fetch-in-typescript)

And I am trying to implement this:

```
private api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
        return fetch(url)
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(response.statusText)
            }
            return response.json<T>()
          })          
}
```

However the compiler shows the error:

[ts] Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

I am not sure what the problem is but basically I am trying to implement a class which wraps the API calls to return an array of items and I have experimented with async/await and nothing seems to quite work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `response.json()` is not a generic method but you are trying to make it generic

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like this to cast it to a particular type of `Promise` e.g `return response.json() as T` or `return <T>response.json()`

Answer (score 16):

Seems that signature is not there anymore, **Instead** use this code:

```
response.json().then(data => data as T);
```

Yeah, that will return you a strong typed data. 
Below the complete code snipped.

```
private api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText)
        }
        return response.json().then(data => data as T);
      })          
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error with Express when I forgot this import:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

The complete example becomes:

```
// controllers/my-controller.ts
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export const someMethod = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I found one problem with answer above.
If you have JSON body like this

```
{ "error" : "{ "message" : "some message" }" }
```

code above will return object with one key error and "{ "message" : "some message" }"
So it's better to use

```
JSON.Stringify(data)
```