# How would I make this code pull the JSON from a url instead of having it in the script

Tags: json, ajax, typescript, api, server

I want to make the JSON you see in the script below get pulled from an API instead of being in the script itself. I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I'm fairly new to TypeScript, so forgive me if I sound like a noob :)

```
export class FaqFakeDb
{ 
    public static data = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "question": "test1",
            "answer": "test1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "question": "test2",
            "answer": "test2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "question": "test3",
            "answer": "test3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried everything and cannot seem to get it working. Any help would me much appreciated.

p.s. Anyone looking to answer could you please include my code or give the full script because I'm not too familiar with the structure of Typescript yet, thanks.

Comment: Can your let us know what you have tried and how it is not working?

Comment: We'd be here all day if I gave all the examples, I tried this one to no avail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103360/how-to-use-fetch-in-typescript

Comment: @DanielFaulkner people in this community tend to prefer to work off incomplete non-working code and improve it, instead of writing the entire solution for anyone that asks. We have all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code an API really quickly using [Express](https://expressjs.com). Here's a quick and simple way to setup one that will serve your data:

1. Navigate to `/where/you/want/your/server/to/be` (chose a directory that will host an NPM project)
2. Initiate an NPM project: `npm init -y`
3. Install express: `npm install express`
4. In `./data.json`, paste your data (`[{"id": "1", "question":...`)
5. In `server.js`, code a server that will serve your data over HTTP:

```
    const express = require('express');

    // create an express server
    const app = express();

    // serves the 'data.json' at the path '/data'
    app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/data.json`);
    });

    // launches the server on localhost, port 8080
    app.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:8080');
    })
```

And that's it! You can navigate to a browser at `localhost:8080/data` and you'll see your data being returned. Alternatively, you can programmatically fetch your data using JavaScript:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8080/data')
  .then(resp => resp.json()) // parse the JSON data
  .then(data => console.log('received data:', data)); // logs the data
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I already have the API setup I'm just having trouble getting it to output in the format above??

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up a server with a route that would then *serve* that JSON in response to a GET request.

If you want to practice, I recommend using public APIs that already have "fake" data.

[www.swapi.co](https://swapi.co) is one example, returning data related to StarWars.