# Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my CommentResponse interface, which is the structure of an object inside the array from API response

```
interface CommentResponse {
  body: string;
  email: string;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  postId: number;
}
```

While setting the data from the API response using setAllComments (useState-hook), I'm getting the following error

```
/typescript-demo/src/components/Dashboard/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /typescript-demo/src/components/Dashboard/index.tsx(35,20):
Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<CommentResponse[]>'.
  Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'CommentResponse[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2345
    32 |     comments = await comments.json();
    33 |     console.log(comments);
    34 |     // comments = await JSON.parse(comments);
  > 35 |     setAllComments(comments);
       |                    ^
    36 |   };
    37 | 
    38 |   useEffect(() => {
```

@RajaJaganathan

```
const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState<CommentResponse[]>([]);

  const commentService = async () => {
    const COMMENTS_API = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`;    
    let comments = await fetch<Array<CommentResponse>>(COMMENTS_API);

    comments = await comments.json();
    console.log(comments);

    setAllComments(comments);
  };
```

I visited other StackOverflow & Google links, but couldn't get the solution

Comment: Can you show your useState code too ?

Comment: @RajaJaganathan , I've edited above, please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case response from fetch it is returning an object with `Object` type
which has values as
`Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments", redirected: false, status: 200…}`

get your interface at right place :

```
const COMMENTS_API = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`;    
let comments =  await fetch(COMMENTS_API);

let result: Array<CommentResponse> = await comments.json();

setAllComments(result);
```

you can use both type `result:Array<CommentResponse>` or `result:CommentResponse[]`.

check code [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-interfacebug?file=Hello.tsx) for both fetch and axios.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `comments` is a Response object. To extract the value from it,  you'll need to call `.json()` on it.

It looks like the generic from `.json` was removed, so you'll have to use type assertion:

```
fetch('some-api')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(comments => setAllComments(comments as Array<CommentResponse>))
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error now- 
```
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.  TS2558

    30 |     let comments = await fetch(COMMENTS_API);
    31 | 
  > 32 |     comments = await comments.json<Array<CommentResponse>>();
       |                                    ^
    33 |     console.log(comments);
    34 |     // comments = await JSON.parse(comments);
    35 |     // setAllComments(comments);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to convert Promise object into an array using async/await?
comments = await comments.json<Array<CommentResponse>>();

this is throwing this error - Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

Comment: This is throwing error because CommentResponse interface doesn't expect any argument

Comment: I took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103360/how-to-use-fetch-in-typescript) for granted, looks like I'm doing something wrong somewhere, one sec...

Comment: Conversion of type 'Response' to type 'CommentResponse[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

This is what I'm getting now :(

Comment: That error should not occur with the code in my answer - the only Response expression is the `res`, which never gets converted to `Array<CommentResponse>`. Make sure you're using `.then(res => res.json()).then(comments => setAllComments(comments as Array<CommentResponse>))` exactly.