# Using fetch in Typescript with data transformations

Tags: typescript, fetch

Im trying convert js code to ts, аnd i have this:

```
function api<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json().then((resJson: T) => ({
        ok: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
        body: resJson,
      }));
    })
    .then((res) => {
     if (res.ok) {
       return res.body;
     }
     return Promise.reject({
       status: res.status,
       message: res.body.message,
     });
    });
}
```

I dont know how to solve the problem with

```
message: res.body.message // Property 'message' does not exist on type 'T'
```

My body-response contains the "message" property  as an optional only if res.ok === false. How to solve this case?
Approximate usage:

```
type ResBody = {
  success: boolean;
  message?: string;
  data?: string[];
};

api<ResBody>("https://example.com")
  .then(({ success, data }) => {
    console.log(success, data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message, err.status)
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain your use of generics here? Specifically generic type `T`? How is `api<T>` called? In other words, how is the type of `T` actually determined. The final `res.body` is of type `T` because you made that so in the earlier `body: resJson` and by declaring above that that `resJson` is of type `T`... But `T` has no message property because it is of unknown type! Give me details and I can solve this pretty easily. Or provide an [mre].

Comment: Added changes to the post

Comment: Again, can you explain why `api<T>` is using generics in the first place? i.e. why are you not just saying `resJson: ResBody`? There has to be a reason to use generics. The answer is important for providing the correct solution. Otherwise my answer below is a best guess / hack.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn ts, and I took an example with generics from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103360/how-to-use-fetch-in-typescript)

Comment: ok, my bad. Promise is defined as generic so that you, the user, can load it with any resolve type, and then be able to reference it in the results. In that case my answer will do the trick... but I will update it in a few minutes with more details.

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanation and another option. Good luck learning Typescript and generics!

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Promise type has a generic parameter `T` so that you can declare the return type of the async function. This allows you to reference that return value in a type-safe way.

Your first `then` returns an object with `body` assigned a value of type `T`, and then your next `then` takes it as its `res` input. This means that `res` is inferred to have a `body` of type `T`. You then reference `res.body.message`, but no where have you declared that type `T` is a type with a field `message`.

You need to do that when you declare the generic parameter `T` in the `function api<T>` declaration as follows:

```js
function api<T extends ResBody>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json().then((resJson: T) => ({
        ok: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
        body: resJson,
      }));
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.body;
      }
      return Promise.reject({
        status: res.status,
        message: res.body.message,
      });
    });
}
```

`T extends ResBody`  tells Typescript that the generic type `T`, whatever it ends up being, will be a ResBody or a subtype of it, and thus will have an optional `message` field of type `string`.

You can be even more generic than that, i.e. if `T` can be *any* type that contains a `message` field as follows:

```js
function api<T extends {message?: string}>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json().then((resJson: T) => ({
        ok: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
        body: resJson,
      }));
    })
    .then((res) => {
     if (res.ok) {
       return res.body;
     }
     return Promise.reject({
       status: res.status,
       message: res.body.message,
     });
    });
}
```

`T extends {message?: string}`  tells Typescript that the generic type `T`, whatever it ends up being, has an optional `message` field of type `string`.