# Typescript - How to map an object with nested objects/types

Tags: typescript

New to Typescript.

I'm trying to create an object from an API call, I only want to pass to this new objects some data. This objects will store a list of objects that will contain an id, a name and content.

I've created a type:

```js
type JokesData = {
    jokes: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        content: string;
    };
};
```

This is my function to get the data and generate object:

```js
export const getJokes = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/jokes");
    const data = await res.json();

    const jokesList: JokesData = {
        jokes: data.docs.map(({ id, name, content }) => ({
            id,
            name,
            content,
        })),
    };

    return jokesList;
};
```

My question is how can I pass the id, name, and content type when I map the object?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7SED.png)

Please, any help on this will be very appreciated!
Cheers!

Added a new type an I nested it the JokesData type

```js
// types
type JokesData = {
    jokes: JokesDataItems[];
};

type JokesDataItems = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    content: string;
};
```

the function that maps the object

```js
export const getJokes = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/jokes");
    const data = await res.json();

    const jokesList: JokesData = {
        jokes: data.docs.map(({ id, name, content }: JokesDataItems) => ({
            id,
            name,
            content,
        })),
    };

    return jokesList;
};
```

It still doesn't work, when using this jokeList in a component the types aren't passed properly.

Update Answer thanks to Nuridin

This works:

```js
type JokesData = {
    docs: JokesDataItems[];
};

type JokesDataItems = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    content: string;
};

// get a list of jokes
export const getJokes = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/jokes");
    const data: JokesData = await res.json();

    return {
        jokes: data.docs
            .splice(0, 5)
            .map(({ id, name, content }) => ({ id, name, content })),
    };
};
```

Comment: Have a look at this article... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471725/14027764 . I think this is what you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use fetch in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103360/how-to-use-fetch-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

**.json** method returns you **any** type, because of this, you have such a mess.
You need to update this line:

```
const data = res.json() as {docs: JokesDataItems[]}
```