# How to type normal fetch() return value

Tags: typescript, eslint

```
type Activity = {
  activity: string
  type: string
  participants: number
  price: number
  link: string
  key: string
  accessibility: number
}

async function fetchOne(): Promise<Activity> {
  const url = "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity"
  const res: Activity = await fetch(url).then(res => (res.json()))
  // Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  // how to fix this? 
  return res
}
```

I got :

> Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: What line thows the error?

Comment: Use `res = ... as Activity` rather then `res: Activity`

Comment: @jcalz yes! You are right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103360/how-to-use-fetch-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestion on how to fix this?

You can't.

The return type of an operation over the wire is fundamentally, logically *unknowable* at compile-time. You can't statically analyze something like that. The proper return type of `response.json()` should really be `unknown`.

All you can do with dynamic data is add *runtime* checks to ensure that it conforms to the schema you want and move the data into type-safe constructs:

```
type Thing = {
  a: string
  b: number
}

async function getTheThing(): Promise<Thing> {
  const resp = await fetch('someurl');
  const data: unknown = resp.json();
  if (typeof data === 'object' && data && 'a' in data && 'b' in data && typeof data.a === 'string' && typeof data.b === 'number') {
    return {
      a: data.a,
      b: data.b
    }
  }

  throw new Error('bad data!')
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8BQUoCGAXFAM7ABOyKeUARiUgK4C2dEFOAvjjgaSCQBjKADMmw4AgD2SKCgjB4EeNQAUAShIAFCtJYJSEADyrUAPmy0hs8lAoRSYDIQDuBBMDGKhcNQHJSfQgmCgAbfw0AbmtbLwATAmBiKAkAayRpVzlMBycAOgArIKRNGPwEUSg1UEhpKsTkjHRMf2k6QoghYH8oADI+qEaCfsH-Al7kIaSRgah-Okm5YdGoWoh66eT8kZbW8ipUXrn1zeH8umbW5jYOSKt8fAdgULlcR8eU84IAGloPhhbAgXf5QHj4Hi0YBwPSuKBICBwgCiFD0FACdAI8SBAEJItwcEA)

Note the compiler accepts this without any unsafe casts. Also note the cumbersome conditional logic. You can move it into a [user-defined type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to make it a little more ergonomical to use.

Comment: You could also look into a library like [`zod-fetch`](https://github.com/mattpocock/zod-fetch) by Matt Pocock. It lets you pass a `zod` schema to `fetch` using a convenience function. See the [unit test](https://github.com/mattpocock/zod-fetch/blob/main/src/createZodFetcher.test.ts) for some example usage.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes you can *automate* the generation of the checks using that, but you still have to make them: there's no purely compile-time solution.