How to typesafe fetch from third party REST API in NextJS 14 App router in RSC and RCC?
There are a lot of different information out there on how to fetch data in NextJS 14.
However I can't seem to find the best way to typesafe fetch data from a third party REST API for RSC as well as RCC?
I'll give an examle:
I have a page (RSC) that needs to fetch the users from a third party REST API. At the moment I have this:
Page.tsx
type SearchParamsType {
  searchParams: {
    [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
  };
}

export async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: SearchParamsType) {
  const session = await getSession();
  if (!session) return null;

  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/users/all`,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + session.user.access_token,
      },
      next: { tags: ["users"] },
    }
  );

  // data is typed as any.
  const data = await res.json();

  // Table is a RCC where i display all the users. The table also mutates the data, when 
  // the data is mutated, the user data needs to be refetched.
  return <Table users={data} />;
}


Perhaps this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471725/3084820

Thanks for your reply! However i was thinking into maybe using react-query or tRPC if that makes any sense?

Well, if you have a solution in mind, then I suggest trying to implement it, and then reframe your question around any issues you have.  Questions seeking library/framework/service recommendations usually get closed as being off-topic on SO.  See #4 here

This question asks for "type safe", the linked question 49471725 asks for "type casting", that's different. We should be clear about what we mean by "type safe". - The linked answer suggests "blind" type assertions, which is a trivial solution IMO, and means TS will not help at all if the incoming data is wrong. Corrected me, but I don't see a real solution other than verifying the input before entering the typescript world (e.g. using custom type guards).

Yep, clarification from the OP would be good.
